# Rebuild Model file from migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had a complete `models.py` file. Unfortunately, some of my  `model` `class` has been deleted. But I did `migration` before this incident happened.

My Question is,

> **Is it possible to rebuild the models.py from last migrations?**

Or I have to rewrite the `model classes`.

Comment: model class has been deleted? Have you made migration again after deleting? You can add those class again and make migration to add it. That's the simple way.

Comment: Yes, I migrated after deleting.

Comment: do you use version controlling? If you use git, then check your commits, and find in which commit the model was deleted, and either revert that commit or copy paste files from that commit

Comment: I use git but, for the new changes there was no commit.